# Span ocupies whole div after line break

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Good evening! I am trying to center a two lines span. If the width of the screen is big enough for the span to keep everything on the same line it is fine, it is centered and the span background wraps the text. If i go for a small width though, it will break in two lines and have the span background full width. I want to keep the blue background wraping the text span. What is this behaviour? Also if i do not put text-align: center; the span on two lines will not even be centered, so the flex is not considered.

html:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.text-container{
  background-color: red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align:center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
   <span class="text">OPORTUNITATI PROFESIONALE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: When the width of the device is so small that the text in the span break in 2 lines, the span width and height will be 100% of the parent, and i don't want that, I want to wrap the text

Comment: If you add  `white-space: nowrap;` to `.text`, will you get what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It just stops the text from breaking into 2 lines